# Update table based on params passed

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to figure out how I can update only specific columns in a table. If I have six columns in a table, is it possible to update just the ones for which the param is passed?

I have following `update` method in a controller.

```
def update
  customer_details = Customer.find(params[:id])
  customer_details.update!(col1: params[:param1],
                           col2: params[:param2],
                           col3: params[:param3],
                           col4: params[:param4],
                           col5: params[:param5])
  head :no_content
end
```

When I pass just `param2` and `param3`, I want to update just `col2` and `col3`. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
attributes = {
  col1: params[:param1],
  col2: params[:param2],
  col3: params[:param3],
  col4: params[:param4],
  col5: params[:param5]
}
attributes.select! { |_k, v| v.present? }
customer_details.update!(attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what you mean by passing only `param2` and `param3`.

- If you have `params`, whose `:params2` and `:params3` keys and values are missing, then nothing special is needed. Just do:

  ```
  customer_details.update!(params)
  ```
- If you have `params`, whose `:params2` and `:params3` values are `nil`, then do:

  ```
  customer_details.update!(params.compact)
  ```